# How to set specific value is first in order from the list in django or python

Tags: python, django

How to set specific values first in order from the list in Django or Python.

```
"Ex: 

    'entity': [   OrderedDict([   ('id', 14),
                                  (   'brand',
                                      OrderedDict([('id', 15),
                                                      (   'title',
                                                          'Golds Gym Long '
                                                          'Branch') ]),
                                                     
                  OrderedDict([   ('id', 241),
                                  (   'brand',
                                      OrderedDict([('id', 230),
                                                      (   'title',
                                                          'New York Fitness & '
                                                          'Nutrition'),
                                                      ]),
                  OrderedDict([   ('id', 367),
                                  (   'brand',
                                      OrderedDict([('id', 309),
                                                      (   'title',
                                                          'new distributors')])]);
```

I expected result is given key value is first order, then ordering from the list using the sorted function in Python.

**expected result:**

"

Comment: Exactly what value do you want to put first?

Comment: expected result is 241 id list is first in order, i need re arrange the list like i given id value is first in order

Comment: but that part is not an `OrderedDict`: that is a  list: the `entity` maps on a lsit, so you can do list manipulation with the elements. That the elements are themselves `OrderedDict`s doesn't matter.

Comment: i need just re order the OrderedDict by specific id value

Comment: id 241 need to put first